# matrix multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, math, matrix

I have a number of `3x3` matricess that I want to multiply together For example:

```
m1*m2*m3*m4*m5
```

Although MTL is a recommended way, I don't have this library and can't use it.

Can someone please suggest a conventional way to multiply these `3x3` matrices (all matrices m1 to m5). Code snippet (for matrix multiplication and multiplying n matrices together) or pointer to some online code will be very useful

Comment: How are the matrices defined?

Comment: Is performance critical? Do you need to use your platform's vector extensions? (Would that be SSE?)

Comment: I wrote a set of tensor math classes once...picky detailed work, but not hard if you're not reaching for screaming fast performance. Be more specific and we might be able to help.

Comment: What exactly is it about the matrix multiplication that you don't know? The definition? Implementation? Operator overloading? What the function signature should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [package of very useful math routines](http://willperone.net/Code/Math.zip) including 3x3 matrix multiplication. The C++ template classes are implemented as header files that can be simply dropped into a project. The overloaded operators make code using this package look very clean. You can preview the [implementation of the 3D vector template class](http://willperone.net/Code/vector3.php) online.

Here is a list of all the files in the archive, with those specific for 3x3 matrix multiplication highlighted in **bold**:

- Assert.c
- Assert.h
- intersect.cpp
- intersect.h
- line2.h
- Line3.h
- main.cpp
- Math.dsp
- Math.dsw
- Matrix2.h
- **Matrix3.h**
- matrix4.h
- **MatrixN.h**
- plane.h
- quaternion.h
- random.h
- Rect.h
- Spline.cpp
- Spline.h
- Utility.h
- **vector2.h**
- **vector3.h**
- vector4.h

Answer (score 0):

This site has code for multiplying two 3x3 matrices together: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/resources/code/index.htm#mul3.